# Does IIS FTP include an API to detect when a file upload completes?

Tags: iis, ftp

I'd like to use the IIS FTP server, but I need to be able to tell when a file upload completes for a specific user. I'd rather not rely on watching file changes directly within Windows because I don't think I'll be able to tell if the file upload truly completed or was aborted and might be completed at a later time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom logging provider to do this.  I've implemented something very similar using

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/632/how-to-use-managed-code-c-to-create-an-ftp-provider-that-sends-an-email-when-files-are-uploaded/

as as start.